# __destruct called twice in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, destructor

First: I've already reviewed all the questions I can find about __destruct() and CodeIgniter, and none seem to address the same issue I'm seeing.

Right. That aside. I'll show code first, as the problem will make more sense after reading. (*N.B.: some code redacted, but nothing important to the question. The `Billing::index` function however, is comprises only one space character in production as well as here*)

---

**application/core/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    public $view = '';
    public $data = array();
    public $template = '';

    function __destruct(){
        if(!is_null($this->template) && ($this->template == '')){
            $this->template = 'public';
        }

        if($this->view == ''){
            $this->view = $this->uri->segment(1,'index').'/'.$this->uri->segment(2,'index');
        }

        if(!is_null($this->template)){
            echo $this->load->view('templates/'.$this->template.'/top',$this->data,true);
        }
        echo $this->load->view('views/'.$this->view,$this->data,true);
        if(!is_null($this->template)){
            echo $this->load->view('templates/'.$this->template.'/bottom',$this->data,true);
        }
    }
}

class MY_ProtectedController extends MY_Controller{
    function __destruct(){
        parent::__destruct();
    }
}
```

**application/controllers/billing.php**

```
class Billing extends MY_ProtectedController{
    public function index(){ }
}
```

---

This, loads perfectly. The main "billing" page is just HTML, so the destructor fires the right template and view.

However, I would love to remove the redundant `public function index(){ }`, as it really does nothing.

So if I remove that from `application/controllers/billing.php` so that it's just

```
class Billing extends MY_ProtectedController{ }
```

and visit `/billing`, I get the output I want, however, I get it *twice*.

If I do some test echos, `MY_ProtectedController::__destruct()` is called once, but `MY_Controller::__destruct` is called twice.

**My question is:** why is this the case, and can it be stopped?

I'm not super familiar with CI core, and I figure that by the time I dig far enough to find the controller instantiation, someone here has probably already got an answer. Will of course update this if my own digging turns anything up.

Answer (score 1):

Solution ended up being fairly simple - but credit for spotting this goes to one of our other programmers.

If I put some code in my 404 route to prevent the auto-destructor from running, I only get one set of output.

```
class Index extends MY_PublicController {
    public function not_found(){
        $this->cancel_destruct = TRUE;
    }
}
```

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    $this->cancel_destruct = FALSE;
    function __destruct(){
        if(!$this->cancel_destruct){
            [...]
        }
    }
}
```